# Do I need to install SSL on my server?

Tags: ssl

I have a virtual server with a few websites on it. To be honest I know next to nothing about SSL. When Itry to log in to my servers Web Host Manager or any of my sites Cpanels I get a screen (In chrome) saying "This website is not trusted". Is this because the server needs to have SSL installed on it?

Maybe it's not even to do with SSL, but any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: SSL secures your conecction between your browser and the server. If you have important data there you should install SSL to protect your connection from "sniffing".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK, so do I need to install it on each of the websites or just on the server? Is the reason I'm only getting the "Not trusted" message when I try to log into Cpanel because of the server or because of the site itself not having SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL secures your conecction between your browser and the server. If you have important data there you should install SSL to protect your connection from "sniffing".

SSL is network protocol so you have to install it or enable it on the server.

here is resource for installing/enabling SSL on Apache server:

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm

and here is how to install/enable SSL on IIS:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875

Comment: 'SSL is server certificate' is not correct. SSL is a network protocol, and in all probability it is already installed as part of the server software. Installing an SSL certificate is not installing SSL. Downvote for the confused terminology.